# pygame: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'health_restart'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pygame

это main

```
import pygame
import random
import show_text
import loading
import window
import health

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
FPSclock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)

def run_game():
    game = True
    health = 100
    health_max = 100
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        display.fill(12, 16, 10)

        window.button_ghost_minus("- health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 540, 1, 'health')
        window.button_ghost("restart health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 640, health.health_restart)
        health.health_bar(health, health_max, (50, 50, 50), (50, 120, 30), 100, 100, 20)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSclock.tick(FPS)
```

это window

```
import pygame
import show_text
import health

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
FPSclock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)


def button_ghost_minus(text, color_text1, color_text2, font, font_size, x, y, minus, obj):
    width = len(text) * font_size
    height = font_size
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x < mouse[0] < x + width and y < mouse[1] < y + height:
        show_text.message(text, color_text2, x + 5, y + 5, font, font_size)
        if click[0] == 1:
            show_text.message(text, color_text1, x + 5, y + 5, font, font_size)
            if action is not None:
                if obj == 'health':
                    health.health1 -= minus
                else:
                    pass
    else:
        show_text.message(text, color_text1, x + 5, y + 5, font, font_size)
```

это health

```
import pygame
import show_text
import window

display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pygame.init()

health1 = 100
health1_max = 100

def health_bar_rect(color_max, color, x, y, height):
    global health1
    global health1_max
    pygame.draw.rect(display, color_max, (health1_max + 10, height + 10, x, y))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, color, (health1, height, x + 5, y + 5))

def health_restart():
    global health1
    global health1_max
    health1 = health1_max
    return health1
```

вот это show_text

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)

def message(text, color, x, y, font, font_size): # функция(текст, цвет, x позиция, y позиция, 'шрифт', размер шрифта)
    font1 = pygame.font.Font('Monaco.ttf', font_size)   # 'шрифт1'
    font2 = pygame.font.Font('Marske.ttf', font_size)   # 'шрифт2'
    font3 = pygame.font.Font('hack.ttf', font_size)    # 'шрифт3'
    font4 = pygame.font.Font('ArcadeInterlaced.ttf', font_size)    # 'шрифт4'
    font_none = pygame.font.Font(None, font_size)   # 'любое число или текст в кавычках'
    if font == 'font1':    # Для того, чтобы выбирать шрифты
        show = font1.render(text, True, (color))
    elif font == 'font2':
        show = font2.render(text, True, (color))
    elif font == 'font3':
        show = font3.render(text, True, (color))
    elif font == 'font4':
        show = font4.render(text, True, (color))
    else:
        show = font_none.render(text, True, (color))
    display.blit(show, [x, y])    # Выводит текст на экран в нужную позицию на экране
```

а это ошибка

window.button_ghost("restart health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 640, health.health_restart)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'health_restart'

Сразу скажу я разделила игру на модули, а вот когда сделала жизни то хотела затестить, но вылезла вот такая ошибка ПОМОГИТЕ     ｡･ﾟﾟ*(>д<)*ﾟﾟ･｡

Comment: В `health` -- у вас число, а конкретно `health = 100`, т.е. код у вас пытался сделать `100.health_restart`. А так, советую не злоупотреблять глобальными переменными и сделать через классы. В питоне всё объект, переменные, классы, функции и модули тоже. Поэтому **переменные**, например, **объявленные позже модуля перепишут ссылку на него**

Comment: health1 = 100 я добавила единичку к переменной, но это не помогло.
Если делать класс, то как мне его лучше написать?
Я новенькая и пока не читала про классы.

Comment: проблема была в том, что не заметила это когда убирала лишнее

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами разобрались :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'health_restart'` **в main.py**. Из-за одинаковых имен импортированного модуля `health.py` и переменной `health`, смотрите:

```
import health

...

    health = 100

...

    window.button_ghost("restart health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 640, health.health_restart)
```

В `health` -- у вас число, а конкретно `health = 100`, т.е. код у вас пытался сделать `100.health_restart`. Нужно решить проблему с коллизией имен модуля и переменных.

**Поэтому нужно исправить коллизии названия в main.py**, например:

```
import pygame
import random
import show_text
import loading
import window
import health

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
FPSclock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)

def run_game():
    game = True
    health_current = 100
    health_max = 100
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        display.fill(12, 16, 10)

        window.button_ghost_minus("- health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 540, 1, 'health')
        window.button_ghost("restart health", (39, 176, 11), (39, 176, 64), 'font4', 50, 855, 640, health.health_restart)
        health.health_bar(health_current, health_max, (50, 50, 50), (50, 120, 30), 100, 100, 20)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSclock.tick(FPS)
```

---

**PS.**

А насчет классов... Можно завести класс `Health`, добавить ему свойства и методы.

Накидал простенький пример:

```
display = ...

class Health:
    def __init__(self, value: int = 100, max_value: int = 100):
        self.value = value
        self.max_value = max_value

    def restart(self):
        self.value = self.max_value

    def draw(self, color_max, color, x, y, height):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, color_max, (self.max_value + 10, height + 10, x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(display, color, (self.value, height, x + 5, y + 5))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Health value={self.value} max_value={self.max_value}>'


health = Health()
print(health)
# <Health value=100 max_value=100>

health.value -= 10
print(health)
# <Health value=90 max_value=100>

health.restart()
print(health)
# <Health value=100 max_value=100>

health = Health(value=50, max_value=150)
print(health)
# <Health value=50 max_value=150>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вы меня спасли 
(* ^ ω ^)